# Procedure to display and return something in scheme?

Tags: function, syntax, scheme, definition, function-call

I want my procedure to print something, then return that something. I tried this

```
(define (print x)
    ((display x)
     x))
```

Shouldn't it be as straightforward to say that this procedure displays `x` at first then returns it as it's expressed at the end of the procedure? Well, apparently it is wrong, and that there is something very fundamental I don't understand about Scheme. So anybody, help me understand this. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The posted code has too many parentheses. In Lisp, parentheses have  meaning, express *function call*, not just grouping of operands.

With `((display x) x)`, your code tries to call *as a function* the (unspecified in R6RS Scheme) value returned by the call to `(display x)`,  with the value of `x` as the argument in that function call.  Instead:

```
(define (print x)
  (display x)
  x)
```

works.

Just remove the extraneous  parentheses. They are not harmless.